# SQL CAST AND ROUND

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have created a view which assigns a number to an alphabetical grade and then gets an average from two values and then the average needs to be rounded to 0 decimal values. 
Below is the code where i am trying to round off the figure

```
   ROUND(CAST(AVG(CASE Result WHEN 'O' THEN 5 WHEN 'H' THEN 4 WHEN 'P' THEN 3 WHEN 'E' THEN 2 WHEN 'B' THEN 1 END) , COUNT(DISTINCT s.Area)) AS DECIMAL),0
```

When i execute my select statement with the above code it throws as error saying 
"Incorrect Syntax near 'Cast' expected 'As'"

I am not sure what i am doing wrong. But i am just trying to get an average and then round the figure to 0 decimal values

Sample Data:

```
s.area  Result
1            O
2            H
3            O
4            P
```

Desired Result:
 (Overall Grade) = 17/4 =4.25  then  Round(4.25) = 4

> The issue is fixed now. I used convert to convert to decimal the
>   average value and then i rounded off the figure. Thanks all for your
>   help

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  What is the `count(distinct)`?  What are the two values?

Answer (score 0):

You give a second argument to `cast()` -- `COUNT(DISTINCT s.Area)`. That is not a data type let alone the expected keyword `AS`. I don't know what `COUNT(DISTINCT s.Area)` is supposed to do here? To get the average as a rounded decimal however, I suggest something like

```
round(avg(cast(CASE Result
                 WHEN 'O' THEN
                   5
                 WHEN 'H' THEN
                   4
                 WHEN 'P' THEN
                   3
                 WHEN 'E' THEN
                   2
                 WHEN 'B' THEN
                   1
              END)
          AS decimal),
      0)
```

Comment: I have updated my question with sample data and the desired data as to what i am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

AVG is used to take an Average of 1 column. If you want to take an average of two columns just add two columns and divide by 2.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want:

```
ROUND(AVG(CASE Result
             WHEN 'O' THEN 5.0
             WHEN 'H' THEN 4.0
             WHEN 'P' THEN 3.0
             WHEN 'E' THEN 2.0
             WHEN 'B' THEN 1.0
           END), 
      0)
```

The `cast()` is not needed if you start with decimal values in the `case`.  I have no idea what the `count(distinct)` is supposed to be.  Perhaps that should be another column.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Using decimal values helps but now i want to round the results to 0 decimal places. I am doing average of two columns. One is the case statement and the other Count ( Distinct s.area) and i am getting the correct value i need but i need to round this figure now.

Comment: AVG(CASE Result WHEN 'O' THEN 5.0 WHEN 'H' THEN 4.0 WHEN 'P' THEN 3.0 WHEN 'E' THEN 2.0 WHEN 'B' THEN 1.0 END) AS OVERALL ,COUNT(DISTINCT s.AreaSeq) AS COUNT  is giving me a value as 4.5 but i want it to show as 5

Comment: @JaspreetSaini . . . This answer includes `round()`, but I don't think `round()` will round up 4.5 to 5.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the Round around your average, like this. The indents are optional, I'm just trying to show the different parts at different levels.

```
With TestData as
(
Select 1 as Area, 'O' as Result
UNION ALL Select 2 as Area, 'H' as Result
UNION ALL Select 3 as Area, 'O' as Result
UNION ALL Select 4 as Area, 'P' as Result
)

Select 
  ROUND(
      AVG(
          CASE Result 
          WHEN 'O' THEN 5.0 
          WHEN 'H' THEN 4.0 
          WHEN 'P' THEN 3.0 
          WHEN 'E' THEN 2.0 
          WHEN 'B' THEN 1.0 
          END
      )
  , 0) AS OVERALL ,

    COUNT(DISTINCT Area) AS COUNT

From TestData
```